# I'm getting following error: not all code paths return a value (BepaalTafel). Who can help my fix this

Tags: c#

I want to make a combobox with numbers 1 to 10.

```
private void cbKiesTafel_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 10)
    {
        string KiesTafel = ((ComboBoxItem)cbKiesTafel.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();

        lbTafels.Items.Add(BepaalTafel(KiesTafel));
        i++;
     }
}

private string BepaalTafel(string KiesTafel) (the problem is here)
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 10)
        i++;
    switch (KiesTafel)
    {
        case "1":
            return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*1).ToString());
        case "2":
            return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*2).ToString());
        case "3":
            return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*3).ToString());
        case "4":
            return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*4).ToString());
        case "5":
            return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*5).ToString());
        case "6":
            return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*6).ToString());
        case "7":
            return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*7).ToString());
        case "8":
            return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*8).ToString());
        case "9":
            return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*9).ToString());
        case "10":
            return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*10).ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need `default` section in your `switch` statement.

Comment: Just a side note, but your BepaalTafel method looks weird: What's point of incrementing `i` inside a `while` loop to 10? Your `switch` could be replaced by just int.TryParse(KiesTafel) and a range check (greater-or-equal 1 and  smaller-or-equal 10).

Comment: I tried to answer but I'm not 100% sure if it gives the desired result. Could you explain how the selected `KiesTafel` value influences the `Tafels` items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While all other answers correctly address your issue at hand I would like to point out some flaws in your overall approach:

Your method `BepaalTafel` tries to access a global object which can cause you a lot of trouble and is generally considered bad practice.

Your method returns a string while it already adds to the ComboBox items which is at best redundant.

Instead I'd suggest to use a far simpler way of generating the desired items:

```
private void cbKiesTafel_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string KiesTafel = ((ComboBoxItem)cbKiesTafel.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();

    int kies = 0;
    int.TryParse(KiesTafel, out kies);
    var tafels = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => string.Format("{0} x {1} = {2}", kies, i, i * kies));
    lbTafels.ItemSource = tafels;
}
```

Comment: When i use this method i have always the 10. How can i have a better solution when i click in the combobox.

Comment: When i click on the combobox, the answer should be for example: the 5, 1*5= 5 , 2* 5 = 10, ...

Comment: I modified my example to factor in the selected value from `KiesTafel`. This should give you the desired list of items.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a `default` option:

```
switch (KiesTafel)
{
    case "1":
        return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*1).ToString());
    case "2":
        return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*2).ToString());
    case "3":
        return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*3).ToString());
    case "4":
        return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*4).ToString());
    case "5":
        return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*5).ToString());
    case "6":
        return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*6).ToString());
    case "7":
        return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*7).ToString());
    case "8":
        return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*8).ToString());
    case "9":
        return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*9).ToString());
    case "10":
        return (lbTafels.Items.Add(i + " x " + KiesTafel + " = " + i*10).ToString());

    default:
        return "";
}
```

Unless you place a `default` in there, the compiler will think `Hold on, if KiesTafel is none of the case values, then what am I supposed to return?`

Answer (score 0):

Your `case` statement is not returning a value on all inputs, hence your method isn't either so naturally the compiler will complain.

Add a `default` (it's hit when switch doesn't match any other case) to your `switch` and return something.

```
switch (KiesTafel)
{
    case 1: ...
    case 2: ...
    ...
    default:
        return String.Empty;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your value is neither of your described value (from 1 to 10) then it will not return. Thus you get an error saying not all code paths return value.

You can fix that by adding `default` keyword to the end of your `switch`.

```
default:
    return String.Empty;
```

Another solution could be return something if non of the values are meet. Just at the end of your method write `return String.Empty;`

Answer (score 0):

Add a default case with a return to your switch, or add a return after the switch.